# How to create a Collection in Firestore with node.js code

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I cannot figure out how to create a new Collection with the node.js firestore api.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Collections are automatically created when you add/write a document to them. There is no need (nor API) to explicitly create a collection.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model):

> Collections and documents are created implicitly in Cloud Firestore. Simply assign data to a document within a collection. If either the collection or document does not exist, Cloud Firestore creates it.

Comment: Is it possible to create a document with fields and a subcollection at the time of a root collection creation? I'm finding I need to create my document first, then create my subcollection in two steps

Comment: note that deleting a doc doesn't delete its subcollection! u need to delete subcollection separately.