# How to check if collection and document exists, and if not create a collection and document with a specific ID in FireStore using .net

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore how do you check to see if a collection and document already exists, and if not create a new collection and a document with a specific ID using .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this answer for a node based question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623759/how-to-create-a-collection-in-firestore-with-node-js-code), the collection will be created automatically, but even still, it's not readily apparent how you do this, especially in .NET.  This is even more true if it's multiple collections down the tree.  As an example, here is a class for the document that we are going to try and add:

```
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;

namespace FirestoreTest.Models
{
    [FirestoreData]
    public class ClassicGame
    {
        public ClassicGame()
        {

        }

        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string publisher { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's an example function that performs a check if the collection and document exists at PC/Games/{publisher}/{title} and if not creates it using gameId as the ID for the document.  It is using  *Google.Cloud.Firestore* and *Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1Beta1*

```
public async Task<bool> AddPcGame(string gameTitle, string gamePublisher, string gameId)
        {
            string publisherCollectionPath = "PC/Games/" + gamePublisher;

            //Try and get the document and check if it exists
            var document = await db.Collection(publisherCollectionPath).Document(gameId).GetSnapshotAsync();
            if (document.Exists)
            {
                //document exists, do what you want here...
                return true;
            }
             //if it doesn't exist insert it:  
            //create the object to insert
            ClassicGame newGame = new ClassicGame()
            {
                title = gameTitle,
                publisher = gamePublisher
            };
            //Notice you have to traverse the tree, going from collection to document.  
            //If you try to jump too far ahead, it doesn't seem to work. 
            //.Document(gameId).SetAsync(newGame), is what set's the document's ID and inserts the data for the document.
            CollectionReference collection = db.Collection("PC");
            var document2 = await collection.Document("Games").Collection(gamePublisher).Document(gameId).SetAsync(newGame);

            return true;
        }
```